# Trait for a struct that can be run in its own thread

Tags: multithreading, rust

Suppose that I have a video decoder that implements the `Decoder` trait. It's natural that I want a method that runs this decoder on its own thread:

```
fn run(&mut self) {
    //These are `Arc` so they can be accessed from the thread, but what if they were not?
    let on_consume = on_consume.clone();
    let on_produce = on_produce.clone();
    //launches the thread
    self.stoppable_thread.run(
        format!("ffmpeg_software_decoder_{}", self.domain.name()).as_str(),
        Box::new(move |should_continue: Arc<AtomicBool>| {
            while should_continue.load(Ordering::Relaxed) {
```

As you can see, a problem is that I cannot have references to `self` inside of the thread that is launched. So the method should be instead this:

```
fn run(s: Arc<Mutex<dyn Decoder>>) {
```

This way I can access the decoder's inner variables from inside the thread.

I want a trait with this method, though. Something like this:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

pub trait Runnable<T> {
    fn run(s: Arc<Mutex<T>>) -> Result<(), ()>;
}

pub trait Decoder: Runnable<dyn Decoder> {

}
```

However, this won't work:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0391]: cycle detected when computing the super predicates of `Decoder`
 --> src/lib.rs:7:1
  |
7 | pub trait Decoder: Runnable<dyn Decoder> {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
note: ...which requires computing the super traits of `Decoder`...
 --> src/lib.rs:7:1
  |
7 | pub trait Decoder: Runnable<dyn Decoder> {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  = note: ...which again requires computing the super predicates of `Decoder`, completing the cycle
note: cycle used when collecting item types in top-level module
 --> src/lib.rs:7:1
  |
7 | pub trait Decoder: Runnable<dyn Decoder> {
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

What would be a good solution for this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by running a struct in its own thread. Do you mean move a struct instance into a different thread? It's not very clear what you are asking as you mention a struct in the title but didn't include a struct definition in the question.

Comment: @PeterHall I mean create a thread that uses members from the struct to decode the video.

Comment: This particular compiler error is unrelated to multithreading. It's telling you that you have a cyclical trait bound.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What would be a good solution for this?

Well, that depends a bit on what you are actually trying to do.

First, if you say:

> a struct that can be run in its own thread

I would have rather imagined a trait like this:

```rust
pub trait Runnable {
    /// Process in a fresh thread
    fn run(s: Arc<Mutex<Self>>);
}
```

Why should a 'runnable struct' can run anything else than `Self`, so there is no need to make `Runnable` generic.

If we further assume that your `Decoder` is *processable* (i.e., can be decoded), I would imagine that the trait has a method like this:

```rust
pub trait Decoder {
    /// Process `self`, can take a while
    fn process(&mut self);
}
```

Notice, that it just takes `self`, this gives you easy and direct access to all fields of the implementing struct, which is probably quite useful, when you implement it. Of course, this would not spawn a new thread, so you might not want to call it, but that's ok, because we have the `Runnable::run` function for that.

In my opinion, this breaks down the concept of the individual traits rather nicely. And yet, you can still combine them in a useful way. For instance, you can make a blanked implementation of `Runnable` for all `Decoder`s (tho that will limit the usability of `Runnable` in other contexts), like this:

```rust
impl<T: Decoder + Send + 'static> Runnable for T {
    fn run(s: Arc<Mutex<Self>>) {
        std::thread::spawn(move || {
            s.lock().unwrap().process();
        });
    }
}
```

This blanked implementation mean, that when you implement a `Decoder` you just implement the `process` function, and the `Runnable` implementation that spawns a new thread, is automatically provided for you (that if it is `Sync` and `'static`, but otherwise there is no point in using threading anyway).

You could use it for instance like this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyDecRun {
    foo: u32
}
impl Decoder for MyDecRun {
    fn process(&mut self) {
        // Do something useful ...
        self.foo += 1;
    }
}

fn main() {
    let a = Arc::new(Mutex::new(MyDecRun{foo: 42}));

    // Process via Runnable::run that means in a new thread
    MyDecRun::run(a.clone());
    println!("started");

    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
    println!("final value: {:?}", a.lock().unwrap());
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
}
```

[full example in playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0a181cfae54dcb626a43f75450ddccbb)

---

However, notice that the above assumes that your decoder works 'in-place'. In my personal experience, 'decoders' typically work rather in a 'producer' style. In that case, you would rather like to work with futures and/or channels to pass the result or even the inputs around (which would be different structs), and have a trait that reflects the produce style, like this:

```rust
pub trait Decodable {
    type Output;
    /// Process `self`, can take a while
    fn decode(self) -> Option<Self::Output>;
}
```

Then, if you are just interested in the results of say many `Decodable`s, and you want them to be process in parallel, you can just use [rayon](https://crates.io/crates/rayon) to do processing in parallel for you, making your code much simpler: [full example in playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=daff3f92b5ed119c18cd68d620a01223).

But you can still fiddle with thread and channels yourself if you need to, I mean, it really depends on what you are up to.